Generic defaults trigger error for dependent generic constraint variable
The following interface and function, with defaults for K, V and T:
interface IBST<K = number, V = string> {
    key: K;
    value: V;
    parent?: this;
    left?: this;
    right?: this;
}

function *walkInOrder<K = number, V = string, T extends IBST<K, V> = IBST<K, V>>(tree?: T): Generator<T> {
    if (tree === undefined) return;
    yield* walkInOrder(tree.left);
    yield tree;
    yield* walkInOrder(tree.right);
}

Causes the following error where walkInOrder calls itself recursively (precisely for the expressions walkInOrder(tree.left) and walkInOrder(tree.right)):

Type 'IBST<number, string>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'IBST<number, string>'.ts(2322)

I'm surprised by this because I thought these defaults would be used as a fallback for when the types of K and V can't be inferred from their context, but now it seems to me like generic defaults are not a fallback but something else. What's a good way to think about this situation and generic variable defaults in general?

Curious why you need T? If you remove it then your code works with the defaults for K and V. If that works for you I'll write it as an answer, otherwise what am I missing?

I need T because walkInOrder is wrapped by a BST class method which does the following: *walkInOrderRecursive(): Generator<this> { yield *walkInOrder(this); }. With T, subclasses of the BST class return the correct subtype when calling statisticBST.walkInOrderRecursive().

• "Adding defaults causes the following error" Please make the code actually show the error when copied and pasted, as opposed to requiring someone to read words and then perform actions to get to the [mre].

(see prev comment) • When you call walkInOrder() you get mostly a failure of inference for K and V no matter what, because only T is inferrable from the parameter. Then K and V fall back to whatever, which is unknown if you don't give it a default, and luckily T is assignable to IBST<unknown, unknown> for all T.  But when you give it defaults, then suddently that's not true anymore.  Don't rely on inference when you have poorly conditioned generic type parameters; just call walkInOrder<K, V, T>(tree.left) manually, as shown here.

(see prev comment) Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Added a snippet with defaults.

@jcalz Hm, I think I understand why T may not be assignable to IBST<number, string>, but I still don't understand why the presence of defaults means that IBST<unknown, unknown> isn't attempted before IBST<number, string> is attempted. And what are poorly conditioned generic type parameters? Your solution works for me, but I still can't say I understand at what stage TypeScript resort's to using defaults.

• Why would unknown be attempted? That only happens because K and V cannot be inferred, so it falls back to unknown.  When you provide a default, it falls back to that instead, exactly as you were saying it should. • By "poorly conditioned" I mean that you have no inference site for K or V anywhere. If you have a signature like <T>(x: any)=>void then T will not be inferred no matter what. Neither will T in <T, U extends T>(u: U) => void, because constraints are not inference sites. It's not clear to me what you intend K and V to be, ever. Does this make sense now?

I don't have a good answer for why unknown would be attempted first other than "because not using the provided defaults and sticking to unknown may compile successfully". But then I don't know what heuristic one would use to decide which variables to fill in with defaults, and which to fill in with unknown.
Your explanation about what poorly conditioned means makes sense. In particular, I would have expected K and V to be inferred from the IBST<K, V> constraint on T, but I see now that they won't be.

Okay, so, if I write this up as an answer, is it likely to be acceptable to you? Does anything seem like I'm missing the point or some aspect of your issue?

Yes, I think this conversation has been helpful and I'm sure your answer will be acceptable.
It would also be useful to hear your take on the interplay between generic defaults and the default default of unknown (assuming it's correct to say that the default default is unknown), and when one might want to refrain from specifying a default in order to leave it up to the compiler to use unknown.

That last bit is kind of out of scope here.  Use defaults when you want some default type argument when inference fails.  The "default default" is the constraint, which might be narrower than unknown. If you like that default, then you don't need to specify one. Otherwise you do.

The call signature
<K, V, T extends IBST<K, V> = IBST<K, V>>(tree?: T) => Generator<T>

is fairly problematic because there are no inference sites for K or V.  When you call that function, the type of T can be inferred from the argument for tree (assuming it's passed in at all), but nothing is available from which to infer K or V. You might think that the constraint for T could serve as such an inference site, but TypeScript doesn't work that way.  See microsoft/TypeScript#7234.  There are too many generic type parameters for this function.

So whenever you call that function, unless you manually specify the type arguments, inference will fail for K and V, and they will fall back to something.  If K and V are given default type arguments, they will fall back to those defaults. Otherwise they will fall back to their constraints. Since there are no explicit constraints, they will fall back to their implicit constraint of unknown.
So, let's look at those recursive calls:
Given
function* walkInOrder<K, V, T extends IBST<K, V> = IBST<K, V>>(
  tree?: T): Generator<T> {
  if (tree === undefined) return;
  yield* walkInOrder(tree.left);
  yield tree;
  yield* walkInOrder(tree.right);
}

the type of tree.left and tree.right are T | undefined, and so in those calls, the T type argument for the inner call is inferred as the same as the T type parameter for the outer call.  K and V cannot be inferred, and so they fall back to unknown.  This is like calling walkInOrder<unknown, unknown, T>(tree.left).  The constraint for T is therefore IBST<unknown, unknown>. That is a supertype of IBST<K, V> no matter what K and V are, so it succeeds.
On the other hand, given
function* walkInOrder<K = number, V = string, T extends IBST<K, V> = IBST<K, V>>(
  tree?: T): Generator<T> {
  if (tree === undefined) return;
  yield* walkInOrder(tree.left);
  yield tree;
  yield* walkInOrder(tree.right);
}

the same T is inferred for the inner calls, but now K and V fall back to string and number respectively.  This is like calling walkInOrder<string, number, T>(tree. left).  The constraint for T is therefore IBST<string, number>. This is * not* known to be a supertype of IBST<K, V>, so it fails.  Once it fails, T falls back to its constraint, and now the inner walkInOrder() returns Generator<IBST<string, number>>, which is (for the same reason) not known to be assignable to Generator<T>.

So that's what's going on. I'd say the issue here has little to do with the defaults and everything to do with the fact that K and V cannot be inferred.  If you want to make this work, you can explicitly specify K and V in the inner calls, like
function* walkInOrder<K = number, V = string, T extends IBST<K, V> = IBST<K, V>>(tree?: T): Generator<T> {
  if (tree === undefined) return;
  yield* walkInOrder<K, V, T>(tree.left);
  yield tree;
  yield* walkInOrder<K, V, T>(tree.right);
}

But you'll just run into the same problem when you try to call walkInOrder() outside the call, unless you specify K and V manually, and it's not clear what purpose K and V actually serve since the output type is Generator<T> which doesn't care about K and V at all. You might as well either remove K and V and compute everything from T, or remove T and compute everything from K and V.  This works well:
function* walkInOrder<K = number, V = string>(tree?: IBST<K, V>): Generator<IBST<K, V>> {
  if (tree === undefined) return;
  yield* walkInOrder(tree.left);
  yield tree;
  yield* walkInOrder(tree.right);
}

Playground link to code

Thank you for your answer!
The purpose of K and V is to be type parameters for IBST, and the purpose of T is to allow wrapping walkInOrder from a class while maintaining that the generated nodes are typed according to the calling class's and its subclass's type. Here's a playground to show what I mean.
